# What does curly braces with two number aligned vertically means in a function

Tags: functions

i am reading an article about bloom filter false positive rate and i try to compute this function [the function i am trying to compute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKoHF.png)

however, i don't understand this :
[click this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeLk2.png)

Can anybody tell me what does it means? thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: It means Stirling numbers of the second kind - especially in the context of combinatorics.

Comment: i got it, thanks for the answers